# Rails 3 validate_with throws ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

could anybody explain me why this code

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate
    # nothing here for now
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

throws this exception (when I try to create a model object):

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/data/rubydev/kalpana/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:314:in `validate'
/data/rubydev/kalpana/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:314:in `send'
```

I used [the tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_with) for this one. It should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this 'validate' method raise an ArgumentError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973909/why-does-this-validate-method-raise-an-argumenterror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#validate` method needs to accept one parameter (the model it's validating).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html